# Parsing Hex Numbers from \xNN Format in Lua

Tags: lua

I am reading in some strings that are formatted as follows: "\x0f\x14\xab" in Lua 5.3. These strings contain hexadecimal numbers (in between the "\x" characters) that I would like to extract. E.g. I should be able to parse "0f", "14" and "ab" from the example (string format is fine). How can I do this?

Comment: it's in the [Lua manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)...

Answer (score 0):

```
local text = "\\x0f\\x14\\xab"
```

You simply match the string with a pattern that contains two hexadecimal digits.

```
for hex in text:gmatch("%x%x") do print(hex) end
```

Comment: The strings I'm reading in are not in that format. It would be `local text = "\x0f\x14\xab"`.

Comment: @mchapman you have to escape backslashes... that's how you represent the string you're reading in Lua.

Comment: I understand how escaping backslashes works. I am reading the text in (from a bytecode file) and have no control over how it is formatted.

Comment: you said you read a string "\x0f\x14\xab" and you want to get the hexadecimals between the \x. For me this means that you read the ascii characters "\", "x", "0", "f", ... from (most likely a file). if that is not the case you should have clarified that in your post. if you say bytecode you mean a binary file that you read and you want to convert the read bytes to a hexadecimal representation? explain yourself.

Comment: I do not read individual characters. As I have said, I am reading long strings of the form "\x0f\x14\xab" from a Lua bytecode file, as an interpreter would. Bytecode ~= binary. If you are interested in what a Lua bytecode file looks like, then you could look at something like: http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf

Comment: The tone of your comments is a bit off-putting to me. I do not feel as if anything productive is going to come from this discussion, so I am leaving this thread. Nevertheless, thanks for engaging with me!

Comment: I only told you to explain better what you want as you obviously did not. Note that there is another answer with escaped backslashs....  I'm a German engineer. We say the truth without talking in riddles and hiding behind uneccesary nice words. I'm sorry if that is off-putting to you but that's how we are and what makes us so efficient and successful. We name deficiencies brutally honest. But that's not to put anyone off, it's to reach a common goal asap. Sorry if I hurt your feelings, I just tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an LPeg solution as well

```lua
local lpeg = require 'lpeg'

local hex = lpeg.S('0123456789abcdefABCDEF') ^ 1 / function(s) return tonumber(s, 16) end
local parser = (lpeg.P("\\x")*hex + lpeg.P(1) / error) ^ 1

local text = "\\x0f\\x14\\xab"
print(parser:match(text))
```

the plain Lua version if better for simple cases, but if you want more extensibility LPeg is a good alternative :D

Answer (score 0):

```
for hex in bytes:gmatch(".") do 
    str = string.format("%02X", string.byte(hex))
    print(str)
end
```

Comment: Welcome blunde. Kindly update the code using the proper formatting and try to explain it a bit too. Thanks!